# Firebase: check if the supplied password equals the user's

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following function as part of a check if it is OK to generate tokens with subsequent logging in the user. It is supposed to return `true` if and only if the user with the given email has the given password:

```
login = function(username,password) {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(username)
        .then( userRecord => {
            console.log("Success in fetching user: "+userRecord.toJSON());
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log("Error fetching user: "+error);
            return false ;
        });
    return true ;
}
```

How do I user the function argument `password` here? The `userRecord` object only has `passwordHash` and `passwordSalt`, but (perhaps rightly so) not the password itself. Then, how do I do something like `if ( userRecord.passowrd().equals(password) )` ?

Answer (score 0):

Validating a users email and password is not part of the Admin SDK. You would need to use the client SDKs to do this and pass up an ID token which you could then validate.

There is one way ive found to be able to do it but not sure if its supported but there is a rest API that will verify the password and return back an `idToken` property that you can return back to the client.

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=ENTER_THE_FIREBASE_API_KEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "email" : "demo@email.com",
    "password" : "demo123",
    "returnSecureToken" : true
}'
```

`ENTER_THE_FIREBASE_API_KEY` you can get from the firebase console